# How to write the request method type in controller in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, controller, httprequest

I developed a  `SpringBoot` project.

In the service `TaskServiceImpl.java`:

```
 @Override
public Response<Boolean> claimTask(int id, String worker) {
    try{
        taskDao.claimTask(id, worker);
        pictureDao.savePictureList(id, worker, FileTool.listPictureName(FOLDER_NAME));
        return new Response(true, "Succeed to claim task!");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new Response(false, "Fail to claim task!");
    }
}
```

I am using multiple `DAOs` in a service method like `claimTask`, but how should I write the relative controller, like `TaskController`.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "claim", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response<Boolean> claimTask(int id, String worker){
    return taskService.claimTask(id, worker);
}
```

I was doubting about the "method", should I write nothing or just use the "`method = RequestMethod.POST`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was doubting about the "method", should I write nothing or just use
>   the "method = RequestMethod.POST"?

The type of method should be used according to the work your endpoint is doing.

According to [restfulapi](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods) you should use :

1. **HTTP GET**: Use GET requests to retrieve resource representation/information only – and not to modify it in any way
2. **HTTP POST**: Use POST APIs to create new subordinate resources, e.g. a file is subordinate to a directory containing it or a row is subordinate to a database table
3. **HTTP PUT**: Use PUT APIs primarily to update existing resource (if the resource does not exist then API may decide to create a new resource or not)

---

If you are using `Spring version 4.3 or above` you can use [GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html), [PostMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html) etc.

Comment: Thank you, only need to know which is return decides the request?

Comment: sorry, I could not understand this question. Please be a bit clear so that we can help you.

Comment: When I use different dao methods in a service method, in the relative controller,which determines the request? Such in the code I get the

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `@RestController` (It is combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody) in your Controller class. So you can remove `@ResponseBody` in every method.

```
@PostMapping("/claim")
public Response<Boolean> claimTask(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String worker){
    return taskService.claimTask(id, worker);
}
```

I hope `value = "claim"` is URI path.

Comment: **Its better to use @RestController**, what if the application is MVC architecture?

Comment: So just the post method is OK? orz

Comment: @MehrajMalik For Spring MVC architecture also can use `@RestController`

Comment: @Yu.Pan Yes its ok. Please make sure you have that particular spring version. I think its available from Spring 4+

Comment: @Satz REST APIs are meant for sending JSON/XML data that's why they are called **REST**. in MVC you send a template name to be rendered.

Comment: @MehrajMalik I totally agree with your point. According to this question and question tag I have given my answer.